# Diagnostic accuracy meta-analysis using MADA in R

Tags: r, meta-analysis, accuracy, diagnostic

After using the bivariate model I got a pooled sensitivity and false positive rate. How do I calculate the likelihood ratios, specificity etc with confidence intervals from here on? Can it be done using MADA on R or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use the `mada` R package, by means of the `madauni` command for univariate meta-analysis and the `SummaryPts` command for bivariate meta-analysis (the latter being recommended for instance by [Zwinderman and Bossuyt](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2992/abstract)). A suitable example follows:

```
install.packages("mada")
library("mada")
data(AuditC)

# univariate meta-analysis
negLR.DSL <- madauni(AuditC, type = "negLR", method = "DSL")
summary(negLR.DSL)
forest(negLR.DSL)
negLR.MH <- madauni(AuditC, type = "negLR", method = "MH")
summary(negLR.MH)
forest(negLR.MH)
posLR.DSL <- madauni(AuditC, type = "posLR", method = "DSL")
forest(negLR.MH)
summary(posLR.DSL)
forest(posLR.DSL)
posLR.MH <- madauni(AuditC, type = "posLR", method = "MH")
summary(posLR.MH)
forest(posLR.MH)

# bivariate meta-analysis
fit <- reitsma(AuditC)
mcmc_sum <- SummaryPts(fit, n.iter = 10^6)
summary(mcmc_sum)
```

Comment: The OP did say s/he was using a bivariate model so I suspect SummaryPts is the function s/he needs.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks, I had misunderstood his request, I have amended the code and now supply a more comprehensive code

Comment: No I meant SummaryPts not summary.

Comment: @mdewey I don't follow now. Isn't the updated code correct?

Comment: I think your edit had not made its way through when I made my comment, I may have been seeing a cached version.

Comment: @mdewey Very well